# Why does my inline JQuery code work, but that in `javascript` directory of theme does NOT work?

Tags: jquery, moodle

I am running Moodle 2.6.5. I am writing a Moodle theme, and the ***JQuery code in `.js` files*** in the `javascript` directory of the theme was working a while ago, and since then I've been making changes to the PHP and CSS, but I don't think I changed anything in Javascript part or anything related to JavaScript.

Today I checked and found out that it is not working, ***while any inline JQuery code added to the layout files works.*** I confirmed by adding an alert statement at the top of a Javascript file `<moodle-root>/theme/testy/javascript/slideshow.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Meh!');
    ...
});
```

**which did not work**. Then I added the following script to the end of the `<moodle-root>/theme/testy/layout/frontpage.php`:

```
...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('Nah!');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**which works.**

---

***STEPS I FOLLOWED TO ADD JQuery:***

1. In `<moodle-root>/theme/testy/lib.php`:

   ```
   function theme_testy_page_init(moodle_page $page) {
       $page->requires->jquery();
   }
   ```
2. In `config.php`:

   ```
   $THEME->javascripts = array('slideshow', ...);
   ```
3. Then in `<moodle-root>/theme/testy/javascript/slideshow.js`:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       alert('Meh!');
       ...
   });
   ```

which does not alert anything.

**Why is this happening? WHat should I do to fix it?**

Comment: what is your include for the js file, has your file structure changed?

Comment: @depperm Hey thanks it had started working after I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot.'/theme/testy/javascript/slideshow.js';  ?>"></script>` at the end of the `body`. So if you can post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: i think you can answer your own question and accept it